# Pure virtual class has no member named

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a data persistence level so I create a pure virtual class IDbAdapter that provide some functions. After that I develop a class MySQLAdapter that derive IDbAdapter and implement all the pure virtual functions.
This the code:
IDbAdapter.h

```
#ifndef IDBADAPTER_H
#define IDBADAPTER_H

#include <Message.h>
class IDbAdapter
{
  public:
    IDbAdapter() {};
    virtual ~IDbAdapter() {};
    virtual int insertMessage( Message *msg ) = 0;
}
```

MySQLAdapter.h

```
#ifndef MYSQLADAPTER_H
#define MYSQLADAPTER_H
#include <IDbAdapter.h>
#include <Database.h>
#include <Message.h>

class MySQLAdapter : public IDbAdapter
{
  public:
    MySQLAdapter( Database *db );
    virtual ~MySQLAdapter();
    int insertMessage( Message *msg );
 private:
   Database *_db;
}
```

MySQLAdapter.cpp implement insertMessage() executing the query on the Database instance and returning a code error.
The problem is the main.cpp that look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <IDbAdapter.h>
#include <MySQLAdapter.h>
#include <Message.h>

#define db_host "tcp://127.0.0.1"
#define db_username "user"
#define db_password  "pwd"
#define db_name "test"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int insertdb(IDbAdapter *idba)
{
    MQTTMessage *m = new MQTTMessage("CIAO","CIAOCIAO");
    return idba->insertMessage(m);
}

int main()
{
    Database *db = new Database( db_host, db_username, db_password, db_name );
    MySQLAdapter *dba = new MySQLAdapter( db );
    MQTTMessage *m = new MQTTMessage("Message1","Hi All");
    int result = DB_ERROR;
    result = insertdb(dba);
    cout << "Message inserted: " << result << endl;

    delete m;
    delete dba;
    delete db;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

MySQLAdapter.cpp and Database.cpp are compiled in a shared library named libmydb.so.
Now, when compile I have this error on insertdb() function:
 "class 'IDbAdapter' has no member named insertMessage"
Where is the problem?

Comment: `idba->insertMessageOUT`?

Comment: `return idba->insertMessageOUT(m);` There is no member function `insertMessageOUT` in `IDbAdapter`.

Comment: The error text you quoted says `insertMessage`, but the insert call in `insertdb()`  is `insertMessageOUT()`, which does not exist.  Are you sure you quoted that error text exactly?

Comment: Sorry, my error. I edited the question. The compile error is exact. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is probably `class 'IDbAdapter' has no member named insertMessageOUT`.

That's because `IDbAdapter::insertMessageOUT` doesn't exist.